# How can I predict patterns in user input?

Tags: language-agnostic, prediction

I am working on software in which the user may select multiple substrings from an arbitrary string. Sometimes, this will naturally result in patterns. E.g.:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
 - substring selected: brown fox
"The quick purple fox jumps over the lazy dog"
 - substring selected: purple fox
"The quick orange fox jumps over the lazy dog"
 - substring selected: orange fox
```

So it would seem that the user is always selecting the characters "fox" and the word immediately preceding it.

It would be really neat if I could implement some subroutine that could offer "Predictions" for these substrings, which the user could either make use of, or discard as appropriate. E.g.:

```
"The quick yellow fox jumps over the lazy dog"
 - suggested substring: yellow fox (ACCEPTED)
"The quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog"
 - suggested substring: red fox (ACCEPTED)
"The English Foxhound is a scent hound, bred to hunt foxes by scent."
 - suggested substring: hunt fox (REJECTED)
```

Generally speaking, how would one identify patterns in user input programatically, and use those patterns to make predictions about future input?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a neural network!  Interesting question, but probably off-topic.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Do you have a suggestion as to where it might be better answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been research on this in the field of text editing. There, the idea is to have the user edit a semi-structured text and to replicate the changes to similar portions of the text (with the appropriate transformations).

The general idea is to generate candidate patterns and rank/dismiss them based on user input and heuristics.

See for example [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rcm/papers/iui02/iui02.html) for a nice overview.